# Как избежать дублирования кода при работе NUXT.js и Axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

Всем привет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Такой вопрос:
Если похожий код (как на примере) дублируется в разных компонентах но с небольшими отличиями в названии того что я передаю в параметрах функции

Какие есть варианты вынести все это дело куда то отдельно в нуксте и потом внедрять кастомно параметры?
(для каждого компонента индивидуально)

Стоит ли это делать через плагин?
Если да - то каким образом потом внедрять индивидуально нужные параметры на компонентах + как подключать плагин именно только на этих компонентах и нигде больше?

Comment: Потом когда у вас будет 100500 методов обращение к апи я вам сочувствую, нет ничего плохого в том что бы писать каждый раз axios.метод

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вся суть метода в axios запросе, то мб перенести это в Vuex action. И туда передавать параметры. А в компонентах просто будешь dispath`ить его с тем,что тебе необходимо.
Я бы на такой вариант глянул.